# mkswap fails to create a file

Tags: linux, swap

I was attempting to create a swap file:

```
  mkswap -f /var/swap
```

I get "/var/swap No such file or directory"

Am I supposed to create the file first? The documentation I found does not say that, so I am concerned.

Comment: This really belongs on unix.se, voting for SU as the most appropriate option offered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to create the file first. `dd` is the standard choice:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap bs=1024 count=131072
mkswap /var/swap
swapon
```

this'd create a 128meg swap file.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It worked.  :-) With one edit: swapon /var/swap - the filename is required.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you run `mkswap` on a partition, not a file.  Since one wouldn't expect it to edit the partition table for you, it's written to expect the target to already exist.

Answer (score 1):

Snip from man mkswap:

> To set up a swap file, it is necessary to create that file before
>   initializing  it
>          with mkswap, e.g. using a command like
>
> ```
>           # dd if=/dev/zero of=swapfile bs=1024 count=65536
> ```

The "-f" option to mkswap is a bit dangerous too, it's "force". Try it without first...